# How to install the latest TorchVision (0.14.0a0+b18fc23) with pip

Tags: pip, torchvision

How do I download the bleeding edge TorchVision with pip? I tried:

```bash
pip3 install torchvision==0.14.0
```

but this gives me

```bash
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchvision==0.14.0 (from versions: 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.2.post2, 0.2.2.post3, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.7.0, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.11.1, 0.11.2, 0.11.3, 0.12.0, 0.13.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchvision==0.14.0
```

How do I download the latest TorchVision version (0.14.0a0+b18fc23)?

In the previous TorchVision release (0.13.0) there are no Multiscale Visual Transformers (MViT) for the task of action recognition (https://pytorch.org/vision/0.13/models.html#video-classification). In the newer version (0.14.0a0+b18fc23) there are (https://pytorch.org/vision/main/models.html#video-classification). This is why I need the newer version

Comment: Just a clarification to my question and its accepted answer. At the time I wrote my question torchvision 0.14.0 was not yet available through pip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't there is no version 14 available via pip as of yet.

Their Github explains how to install it from source tho:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#from-source

Answer (score 1):

I think you accidentally added "1" instead of "0"

`pip3 install torchvision==0.14.0`

1.14.0 -> 0.14.0

Comment: Actually you are right :). However, 0.14.0 was not available at that time so that would have not worked either. I updated my question based on this. Thx